# How do I use Gmail's Vacation Responder or Canned Responses feature to respond to the From instead of the Return-Path address?

Tags: gmail, google-voice, automation

As described in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/how-do-i-auto-reply-to-text-messages-received-through-google-voice).

Both the Vacation Responder and using a filter to send a Canned Response send the response the Return-Path field of the email, not the From field. Please don't tell me this isn't the standard, I know that. I need a workaround!

I am trying to set up an SMS auto-responder from Google Voice. So I set Google Voice to forward texts to Gmail. But in Gmail there is no way to auto-reply to texts in the same message—it sends a new separate message using the Return-Path address. So, Google Voice does not receive the message because the Return-Path address is a bounce address. So Google Voice does not receive and forward the text back properly, so the auto-reply does not work.

Can anyone help please? It's very frustrating that there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no way to do this with just Gmail.

I suppose one could craft up a custom tool using Google Apps Script, but Gmail alone doesn't give you that kind of control.