# MMS/SMS Autoreply using Google Voice/Gmail Apps sends reply in different SMS thread

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, google-voice

I am using Google Voice, Gmail and Google App Script to implement an 'SMS autoreply' system using the code described here:

[How do I auto-reply to text messages received through Google Voice?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/how-do-i-auto-reply-to-text-messages-received-through-google-voice/158135?noredirect=1#comment145714_158135)

Very cool.....the basics are that Google Voice forwards incoming SMSs to Gmail which has a 'filter' to detect all incoming messages from *@txt.voice.google.com and label them with the 'SMS' label.  A Google Script then runs every minute and pulls all unread Gmail messages tagged with the label 'SMS' and searches the body of the message for keywords and sends a different response depending on the keyword detected.

One of the responses is an 'image' (a map to my house). I tell them to text the word 'map' to my Google Voice number and it automatically replies.

Here is the admittedly small, but irritating, problem:  The **reply arrives in a different SMS thread** with a 'from number' that looks like:

```
3vrrixqsuammaiedffgi9ie262.4xrln.pxxpun.lxv@grandcentral.bounces.google.com
```

The actual Email reply went from Gmail to:

```
15559871234.15559875678.eworiuqw@txt.voice.google.com
```

(mynum.destinationnum.hash@txt.voice.google.com)

This has to do with the fact that the reply is an 'MMS' instead of an 'SMS' and Google Voice redirects it to **grandcentral** which then converts it and forwards it.

The question is, is there a way I can update the above 'To:' address and get the reply to arrive without going via GrandCentral in the same SMS thread on the original sender's device?

I tried having someone send an image to Google Voice forwarding to my Gmail but the "From" address is the same regardless of image or text.

Here is the code I am using in the Google App Script:

```
var SMSlabelObj = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("sms");
var labelThreads = SMSlabelObj.getThreads();
var messages = labelThread.getMessages();

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    var message=messages[i]
    if (message.isUnread()) {
        fromStr = message.getFrom();
        SMSbody = message.getBody();

        searchstring=new RegExp("map","i");
        if (SMSbody.match(searchstring) !== null) {
            URL="https://www.example.com/map.png"
            mapblob=UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL).getBlob().setName("map");
            MailApp.sendEmail({
                to: fromStr,
                subject: "map",
                htmlBody: "<img src='cid:map'>",
                inlineImages: {map:mapblob}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As shown above, I am just getting the 'fromStr' and using that as the 'to' in the reply.
This works great with text replies.  I tried changing 'txt' to 'mms' in the fromStr but that is an invalid address.  I tried various incarnations of htmlBody, attachments, inlineImages and if an image is present, then it arrives via GrandCentral.

Not a huge problem or a showstopper, but irritating.

Comment: Are you actually able to send images to Google Voice? Every way I try incuding App Scripts, reply from gmail, etc ... if there's an image Google Voice ignores it completely.